# Reading from xlsx limited to 65535 rows: openpyxl

Tags: python, django, excel, openpyxl

When I read from an xlsx file containing more than half million entries. pyopenxl reads only 65535 rows.

```
wb = load_workbook(filename=import_file, read_only=True)
ws = wb['Sheetname']
rows = ws.rows # yields upto 65K rows
```

What is confusing is, I have used the same package for the writing operation. I was able to write a million entries to an xlsx file.

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
ws.cell # Write operations here
wb.save(filename=file_path)
```

It will be great if I was able to use the same package for reading and writing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with openpyxl, marked as **WONTFIX**. You can read more about it [here](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/568/cant-read-more-than-65536-lines-from-excel).

The developer team offers a solution to this problem, but mentions that it's a problem with OpenOffice / LibreOffice itself.

> There is a bug in OpenOffice / LibreOffice which creates worksheets with nominal dimensions of up to 65536 rows. openpyxl treats this information as reliable (you can check with ws.max_row as otherwise it has to parse a whole file to find the size, which we want to avoid. You can force recalculation with ws.calculate_dimension(force=True) but the simplest solution is to use iter_rows() with a max_row of 100000.